# Xcode - The executable was signed with invalid entitlements only in RELEASE mode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-entitlements

This question is similar to [The executable gets signed with invalid entitlements in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/xcode-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements). But the difference is that for me it is working for **debug** mode:

[image]

but doesn't work for **release** mode:

[image]

For **release** i got an exception:

[image]

However everything is fine for **DEBUG**: How to make it working for both: release and debug?

Comment: hi, do you have a solution to this problem yet ? I have the same issue

Comment: Yes, I put an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30803855/2725435)

Answer (score 2):

Invariably this error is caused by a mismatch between your provisioning profile and your distribution certificate. Typically, Apple allows an organization to have two distribution certificates and when a provisioning profile is created - it is associated with one or the other. In order to correctly sign an ipa, the distribution certificate AND private key on the Mac where the signing is 
occurring must match that which was selected when the provisioning profile was created.

To check which distribution certificate you have access your keychain

Go to Xcode's Organizer and click on all the Profiles, check if they are valid. Xcode throw up warning text if say, something is missing in Keychain.