# iOS application-identifier has bundle_id repeated twice

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I am trying to build project and it is building fine. when i try to install it on iPhone it gives the following error.

> **The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.** The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements
>   file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.
>   (0xE8008016).

when i checked the entitlements file which is created it had my bundle id repeated twice.

[image: entitlements file]

Answer (score 0):

Search **Code Signing Entitlements** in **Build Settings**, delete it, clean and build the app again.

Don't forget to re-check your code signing

[The executable gets signed with invalid entitlements in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/the-executable-gets-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-in-xcode)

Comment: Code Signing Entitlements is empty

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/the-executable-gets-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

Taj... Clean your build, go to info.plist remove old bundle identifier key and insert your key as **com.companyName.appName** only one time and set team name from setting and select profiles..   and make build again...