# App Crashes Immediately: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have an app installed on an IPad Air via Xcode. For several weeks the application worked fine. Suddenly anytime I opened the app it would immediately crash. The loading screen would appear for a split second and the user would be returned to the home screen. I went and deleted the app, reinstalled it and everything worked fine again. Several weeks later the app kept crashing again. This time I investigated the device logs and found this whenever the app was opened.

```
Aug  4 22:40:47 iPad amfid[240] <Notice>: MIS: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: coolApp.Company'
Aug  4 22:40:47 iPad amfid[240] <Error>: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AAB98943-4336-4E23-8BA6-D785B327DBB5/Company.app/Company not valid: 0xe8008016: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
```

What I'm curious is why did the app work for several weeks then randomly start breaking. The device logs show no crashes. Any help as to why the app closes immediately every time it is opened and how to fix it would be great! Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to downvote a question, at least explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why did the app work for several weeks then randomly start breaking

It's not random at all, as the "several weeks" shows. The entitlement included when you install an app on a device by build-and-run from Xcode has a time limit. You hit that time limit. You did another build-and-run and so you got a new entitlement. You hit its time limit as well. Build-and-run from Xcode is intended for temporary testing, not for long-term installation.

If you are anxious to install your app on your device and have a longer lifetime, do an Ad Hoc build and install by way of iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581225/the-executable-gets-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-in-xcode). Link show the similar issue which you are facing. You need to check the sign in entitlements and then try building it again